# Query containing a CTE running against OLEDB provider failing on one computer but working on another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, oledb, common-table-expression, adodb

I have the following VBScript code which runs just fine on my computer (Windows 7 SP1) but fails to run on another computer (Windows XP SP3):

```
Dim objConn 'adodb connection object
Dim objRS 'adodb recordset object
Dim strQuery
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=" & strDBServer & ";Initial Catalog=BromsunInfo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

strQuery = _
    "WITH CMSRATES AS " & _
    "( " & _
    "SELECT h.EMPL_UNO, h.employee_code, r.rate 'Rate', r.eff_date 'Eff Date' " & _
    "FROM " & strCMSDBServer & ".cmsopen.dbo.hbm_persnl h, " & strCMSDBServer & _
    ".cmsopen.dbo.tbm_persnl p, " & strCMSDBServer & ".CMSOPEN.dbo.TBM_RATE_FEE r " & _
    "WHERE h.empl_uno = p.empl_uno " & _
    "AND p.empl_uno = r.empl_uno " & _
    "AND R.EFF_DATE = " & _
    "(SELECT MAX(EFF_DATE) " & _
    "FROM " & strCMSDBServer & ".cmsopen.dbo.TBM_RATE_FEE R2 " & _
    "WHERE R2.RATE_LEVEL = '1' and member_type='1' AND R2.GROUP_TYPE = '4' AND R2.EMPL_UNO = P.EMPL_UNO) " & _
    "AND r.rate_level = '1' " & _
    "AND r.group_type = '4' " & _
    "AND r.member_type='1' " & _
    ") " & _
    "SELECT bu.UserID, cr.Rate, cr.EMPL_UNO " & _
    "FROM " & strDBServer & ".BromsunInfo.dbo.BromsunUsers bu " & _
    "INNER JOIN CMSRATES cr " & _
    "ON cr.employee_code = bu.Initials " & _
    "ORDER BY bu.UserDisplayName"

With objRS
    .Open strQuery, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    'Do stuff here

    .Close
End With

objConn.Close()
```

The error I'm getting, which happens on the call to objRS.Open, is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'`, which indicates that it doesn't like my use of the CTE.  Here is the query outside of the script:

```
WITH CMSRATES AS
(
    SELECT h.EMPL_UNO, h.employee_code, r.rate 'Rate', r.eff_date 'Eff Date'
    FROM cmsopen.dbo.hbm_persnl h, cmsopen.dbo.tbm_persnl p, CMSOPEN.dbo.TBM_RATE_FEE r 
    WHERE h.empl_uno = p.empl_uno 
    AND p.empl_uno = r.empl_uno 
    AND R.EFF_DATE = 
    (SELECT MAX(EFF_DATE) 
    FROM cmsopen.dbo.TBM_RATE_FEE R2 
    WHERE R2.RATE_LEVEL = '1' and member_type='1' AND R2.GROUP_TYPE = '4' AND R2.EMPL_UNO = P.EMPL_UNO) 
    AND r.rate_level = '1' 
    AND r.group_type = '4' 
    AND r.member_type='1' 
)

SELECT bu.UserID, cr.Rate, cr.EMPL_UNO
FROM dbo.BromsunUsers bu
INNER JOIN CMSRATES cr
ON cr.employee_code = bu.Initials
WHERE ISNULL(bu.BillingRate, -1)<>cr.Rate
ORDER BY bu.UserDisplayName
```

I'm wondering whether there is something different with the OLEDB driver on my Windows 7 machine compared with the XP machine.  I can't understand how the version of the driver would matter, though, since the query would ultimately be run on the database server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you have some sort of load-balancing on the server?  Perhaps it's balancing you between two different versions of SQL (which would be reaaaaally weird, but who knows)?

Comment: @Joe -- No, no load balancing.

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to the same server?  If so then it has to be the driver -- same version of the driver?

Comment: @Hogan -- Yes, definitely the same server.  I googled but couldn't figure out how to get at the OLEDB driver.  ODBC is easy enough, but not OLEDB.  Any idea on that?  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Any chance the security is the problem - are you logged in as the same user on both machines?

Comment: Also, can you (or a dba) see the query as it is passed to the server?  Is it definitely getting passed exactly as you think it should in both cases?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- "it is running a version of SQL Server that didn't support CTEs" -- what is "it"?  I'm targeting the same server, same DB from both machines.

Comment: why use oledb -- why not use native driver?

Comment: @Hogan -- It's an old script, and a large one.  Not going to go through and change things now.  Have other priorities.  But still, that isn't the point, right?

Comment: @Joe -- Thanks for the suggestion.  I used profiler to see what it was passing, and they are actually different.  The offending computer is first prepending `Exec ` to the begging of my statement and, because that fails, it tries prepending `Select *`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
WITH CMSRATES AS
(
```

To this:

```
;WITH CMSRATES AS
(
```

Technically, a CTE does not have to be prefixed with a semi-colon, but the previous statement in the same batch has to be terminated with one. It is likely that in one of these cases the provider or other portions of code are sending other commands along with the batch (could be as simple as `SET NOCOUNT ON`).

As an aside, this is precisely why all of my answers involving CTEs will look like the latter, not the former (and why all of my code samples terminate every relevant statement with `;` - [more info on that here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)). Early on in my Stack Overflow career, I made the mistake of providing answers beginning with a CTE, and people would copy and paste that code into an existing batch, where they weren't using semi-colons at all. Suddenly I got blamed for causing a syntax error that I couldn't possibly have predicted. :-)

Comment: That did it!  I love Stack Overflow.  Thanks a lot, Aaron.

Comment: @roryap *You love Aaron. (FTFY)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Aaron's excellent suggestion, you should check (with SQL Server Profiler or something else) on the server what is being passed by each machine when you have a difference like this.  It's possible something is being passed before the `with` by the offending machine that is solveable by adding a `;` as Aaron suggests, or some other more significant difference.

Comment: Yup.  I just confirmed that (see my response to your comment under my question).